# What does discrete subgroup spans $ \Bbb{C}$ mean?

Tags: elliptic-curves, integer-lattices

What does discrete subgroup of $ \Bbb{C}$ spans $ \Bbb{C}$ mean ?

Lattice is defined as $ \Bbb{Z}+τ\Bbb{Z}$ for some $τ\in \Bbb{C}- \Bbb{R}$.
I heard a proposition which says 'Lattice is discrete subgroup of $ \Bbb{C}$ which spans $ \Bbb{C}$'.

But I'm having trouble to understand what is the definition of 'discrete subgroup of $ \Bbb{C}$ spans $ \Bbb{C}$'.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would assume "span" here refers to spanning as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.  Equivalently, $\mathbb{R}+\tau\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: There are three different concepts in that phrase: "discrete," "subgroup," and "spans." A discrete subset of a topological space is one whose subspace topology is the discrete topology. In Euclidean space, that means all points of the subset are isolated, i.e. each point has a neighborhood small enough it excludes all other points of the subset. Subgroup means closed under addition and subtraction in this context. A subset spans a real vector space if all vectors are linear combinations of elements of the subset, using real coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for all commutes and an answer, very helpful. What is an example of 'discrete subgroup' which is not lattice ?

Comment: $\Bbb Z\times\{0\}$ is a discrete subgroup of $\Bbb R^2$ which is not a lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it spans $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space.

(**Edit:** A discrete subgroup is a subgroup whose subspace topology is discrete. In this case, it's equivalent to saying that around every point there's an open ball containing no other points. The prototypical picture here is the square lattice $\mathbb{Z}[i] \subset \mathbb{C}$.)

It is a theorem, *not* a definition, that the discrete subgroups of $\mathbb{C}$ with this property are the ones of the form $\mathbb{Z} a + \mathbb{Z} b$ where $a$ and $b$ are not real multiples of each other. Then up to [homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothety) (rotation + scaling) we can assume that $a = 1$ WLOG. Then we get lattices of the form $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \tau$ (where $\tau = \frac{b}{a}$) and the spanning condition is that $\tau$ is not real; this gives us every lattice up to homothety which is why this specific collection of lattices is used in the study of elliptic curves (since homotheties between lattices give complex analytic isomorphisms between the corresponding quotients of $\mathbb{C}$).